# multiple form classes in forms.py

Tags: python, django, web

I have a login/registration template (I am using Django) page with a tab for login and another for registration of new users. This means that I have two forms in one template. I am processing them using different views.

I created a forms.py where I put 2 classes like follows:

```
    from django import forms


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username", max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'name': "username",
               'id': "username",
               'tabindex': "2",
               'class': "form-control",
               'placeholder': 'Username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'name': "password",
               'id': "password",
               'tabindex': "2",
               'class': 'form-control',
               'placeholder': 'Password'}))


class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    firstNameReg = forms.CharField(label="First Name", max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'name': "firstname",
               'id': "firstname",
               'tabindex': "1",
               'class': "form-control",
               'placeholder': 'First Name'}))
    lastNameReg = forms.CharField(label="Last Name", widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'name': "lastname",
               'id': "lastname",
               'tabindex': "1",
               'class': 'form-control',
               'placeholder': 'Last Name'}))
    usernameReg = forms.CharField(label="Username", max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'name': "username",
               'id': "username",
               'tabindex': "1",
               'class': "form-control",
               'placeholder': 'Username'}))
    emailReg = forms.CharField(label="Email", max_length=30, widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs={'name': "username",
               'id': "username",
               'tabindex': "1",
               'class': "form-control",
               'placeholder': 'Email'}))
    emailRegConfirm = forms.CharField(label="Email", max_length=30, widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs={'name': "username",
               'id': "username",
               'tabindex': "1",
               'class': "form-control",
               'placeholder': 'Confirm Email'}))
    passwordReg = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'name': "password",
               'id': "password",
               'tabindex': "2",
               'class': 'form-control',
               'placeholder': 'Password'}))
    passwordRegConfirm = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'name': "confirm-password",
               'id': "confirm-password",
               'tabindex': "2",
               'class': 'form-control',
               'placeholder': 'Confirm Email'}))
```

Here is my template:

```
{% extends 'game_webstore/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block body %}


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "game_webstore/login_css.css" %}">
    <script src="{% static "game_webstore/login.js" %}"></script>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="panel panel-login">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <a href="#" class="active" id="login-form-link">Login</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <a href="#" id="register-form-link">Register</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <form id="login-form" action="" method="post" role="form" style="display: block;">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    {% if error %}
                                        <p style="color: red"><strong>* Wrong Username or Password.</strong></p>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ form.username.errors }}
                                        {{ form.username }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ form.password.errors }}
                                        {{ form.password }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                <div class="text-center">
                                                    <a href="" tabindex="5" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <form id="register-form" action="." method="post" role="form" style="display: none;">
                                    {{ form.as_p }}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ form.firstNameReg.errors }}
                                        {{ form.firstNameReg }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ form.lastNameReg.errors }}
                                        {{ form.lastNameReg }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ form.usernameReg.errors }}
                                        {{ form.usernameReg }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ form.emailReg.errors }}
                                        {{ form.emailReg }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ form.emailRegConfirm.errors }}
                                        {{ form.emailRegConfirm }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ form.passwordReg.errors }}
                                        {{ form.passwordReg }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ form.passwordRegConfirm.errors }}
                                        {{ form.passwordRegConfirm }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register Now">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock body %}
```

Here is my view, which is not complete yet:

```
def register_view(request):
    error = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(False)
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=request.POST['password1'])
            login(request, user)

            return redirect('/')
```

My issue is that in the template, it only sees the fields from the first class LoginForm (username and password) and ignores all the other fields. Any suggestions regarding this issue?

Comment: Well, are you using both form classes? You'll need to show your view and template, at least.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added the template and view.

Comment: Where's the part that actually renders the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you pass the 2 forms under two different context names when rendering your template.

For example (in the view):

```
context = {'login_form': LoginForm(), 'register_form': RegisterForm()}
return render(request, 'your/template.html', context)
```

And then in the template, use them accordingly:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ login_form.username.errors }}
    {{ login_form.username }}
</div>
```

and:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ register_form.first_name.errors }}
    {{ register_form.first_name }}
</div>
```

**BTW** the convention in Python is to use underscores rather than camel case variable names. So `first_name` rather than `firstName`.

**BTW 2** it's redundant to have `{{ form.as_p }}` and render each field separately. (e.g. `{{ form.username }}`). Either should be enough.

Comment: The context approach works. Thanks for your comments.